# Removal of tailgate trim on Peugeot 307CC

Tags: peugeot, trunk

I need to work on the inner rear light cluster. How do I remove the lining from the boot lid? I'm assuming this is the way to access the lights

Comment: Can you take a picture? Are the obvious places for screws? Even if there are screws or bolts trim is usually held on by clips. Is it cardboard/felt/whatever trim? It may just be held in by plastic pins.